# Jquery $.get() only sending one parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, api

I have a form, when the submit button is clicked I want to intercept the data and send it to an API. This code sends the first parameter, the Id, but none of the others.

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myForm').children('input').each(function () {
        $.get("/thisismyapiurl/", { Id: $('#dropdown').find(":selected").val(), paramName: this.Name, paramValue: this.Value });
    });
});
```

So the URL is generates is /thisismyapiurl/Id without the other two values. I want it to be /thisismyapiurl/Id/Name/Value

Why is it only sending the first parameter, what can I change so it sends all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery to get name and value of your inputs:

```
$.get("/thisismyapiurl/", { Id: $('#dropdown').find(":selected").val(), paramName: $(this).attr('name'), paramValue: $(this).val()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this)` instead of `this` and `.attr('name')`:

```
{ Id: $('#dropdown').find(":selected").val(), paramName: $(this).attr('Name'), paramValue: $(this).attr('Value') });
```